# How to target an image that comes before all text in a section

Tags: html, css

I have a series of pages, all with the same template. It contains a content block with images and text.

Sometimes an image is at the very top of the content block, and sometimes images come inside the content block between paragraphs.

I need to give the images inside the content block a `padding-top` but if a page has an image at the very top of the content block, I dont want there to be a `padding-top` on the image.

I know it sounds like I could just do `img:first-child: padding-top:0` (or first of type) but if I do that. The first image in every page with the same template will be affected even if it comes inside the content block between paragraphs.

Is there a css or jquery rule to do something like "if an image comes before all text in a certain div, then apply this css"

I could just add a class to every image that comes at the top, but I thought id ask to see if someone knows a way around this.

Here are the mockups.

Say one page has this:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src=""> <!-- this will not have padding top -->

   <p>text</p>

   <img src=""> <!-- this will have padding top -->

   <p>text</p>
</div>
```

The second page has this:

```
<div class="container">
   <p>text</p>

   <img src=""> <!-- this will have padding top -->

   <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Here is the css

```
.container img {
    padding-top: 10px; /* this gives all images a padding top */
}

.container img:first-child {
    padding-top: 0; 
}

/* this makes all first images no padding top but i want it so 
   if an image comes before all text, no padding top while 
   keeping the padding for images within the paragraphs */
```

Comment: `I could just add a class to every image that comes at the top, ` if that's a easy code on your side then I think that's the best bet.

Comment: @j08691 i revised my answer and put in some code

Comment: @RajshekarReddy i was thinking of doing this first but i just wanted to see if there was another way with out doing this

Answer (score 1):

The type of the element doesn't matter. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child):

> The :first-child CSS pseudo-class represents any element that is the
>   first child element of its parent.

---

If you have HTML markup that looks like this:

```
<div class="container>
    <img src="">

    <p></p>

    <img src="">

    <p></p>

    <img src="">
</div>
```

You can style all images, and then change the style of the image, which is also the 1st child of a container:

```
.container > img {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.container > img:first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

---

Or find all images that are the direct children of a container, but not 1st child:

```
.container > img:not(:first-child) {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Even if there are text before image the above selector will still select the image right?

Comment: @OnDron: How does this address the original problem?

Comment: @PHClaus - if an image is the 1st child of all children in the container, it will have a different styling. What do you think?

Comment: That would certainly be the case. However, consider this: We open a <div>, add an  <img> and voila, first child. Now what happens if we do the same but for some reason the source looks like <div>here comes an <img>? Sure enough, img is still first child but no longer at the top. In theory, that's perfectly valid mark-up since div is a block element in its own right.

Comment: @PHClaus - I've considered that. That's why I use 1st child, which is also a direct child '>' of a container - `#container > img:first-child`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your approach. I seem to get confused by /at the very top/

Comment: @OriDrori thanks for your answer, I added some code to my question. will this still work?

Comment: Indeed it will. Your code will as well btw. It's only problem would be the case that @PHClaus mentioned, and I've solved with `.container > img:first-child`

Answer (score 1):

first, add style to give all images a padding top :

```
<style>
    #container img {
        padding-top: 10px; /* this gives all images a padding top */
    }
</style>
```

then remove padding top for first image if exists

```
if ("<img" == $('#container').text().substring(0, 4)) {
   $('#container img:first-child').css('padding-top', 0)
}
```

Comment: The code checks if the first 4 characters inside the div is not `<img` if so add padding top to all img

Comment: I modified the code to support several images in div :)

Comment: the problem is solved ? if yes can please mark the right answer ?